# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Component A to Reactor'

Tags: python, lstm

I have written python code for lstm neural network in python.First I loaded my data and then split my data to 5 sets in the form of an array. Then I feed this data to my network, But I have an error:  ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Component A to Reactor'.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, LSTM, Flatten
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
from keras.preprocessing import sequence

alarm=pd.read_excel('alarmdata.xlsx')

x=alarm['Alarm_tag']

y=alarm['Fault']


c=0
l=0

w=0

k=[[] for j in range(1261)]

for i in range(6305):

    if l<6305:

        while w<5: 

           k[c].append(x.loc[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5
c=0

l=0

w=0

z=np.reshape(k, (1261,5))

n=x.nunique()

q=[[] for j in range(1261)]

for i in range(6305):

    if l<6305:
        while w<5:        
           q[c].append(y.loc[l]) 
           w=w+1
           l=l+1
    w=0
    c=c+1 
    i=l+5 
r=np.reshape(q, (1261,5))

model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(1261, output_dim=64, input_length=5))

model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1261, 5)))

model.add(LSTM(16))

model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(z, r, epochs = 1, batch_size =5)
```

could somebody help me please?

Comment: Does the text 'Component A to Reactor' by any chance come from the excel sheet?

Comment: yes. that is my x feature of data.

Comment: It appears you're trying to convert the text to a float. What line number is the error on?

Comment: yes. In fact I used word Embedding for this purpose. I don't know the error is related to which line. Full error is:  File "F:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Reactor Feed Rate'

Comment: Is that the entire traceback? Usually it will say something like `in line 5 float('a.b') in line 7 .... `

Comment: no. it isn't the entire traceback. other lines are about running the program. but it does't specify the line of error

Comment: @Nathan Hi. 
  File "F:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Reactor Pressure + High'